# Using VW to add noise to reward distribution

Tags: reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I want to add noise to the reward distribution I have.
In what format should the reward distribution be represented for VW to understand and
what methods are available in VW to induce the noise?
For example, you can consider the reward distribution given [here](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/cb_simulation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reward function are essential for a good reinforcement learning algorithm. In your simulation reward function is contributing to reward distribution so one way to add noise to the reward distribution could be (considering the tutorial) to **modify your cost function to give random results**. So in this way you can add noise to distribution.